# MutableStateFlow Best way to reset value after each emission

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I'm currently using an observable value like this:

```
private val _myValue = MutableStateFlow<Long?>(null)
val myValue = _myValue.asStateFlow
```

my composables are collecting my value.

I want myValue to be reset back to null after every emission.

I don't want my composables to have to report back up the chain to the viewModel to reset myValue to null.

Is there something better than StateFlow that I can use for this one-off event?

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. State flow which is automatically reset to null is pretty much a state flow which is always null. What is your use case exactly?

Comment: Yes. The “state” of StateFlow means your app only ever cares about the current, most up-to-date state. Changing it to null means ignore any previous value because the current state is now null. We would have to understand more about what your app is trying to do to suggest a solution. Compose in general only cares about state as far as choosing what it displays. An event system is a whole other beast.

Comment: Let's use the use case of navigation. I want this to fire off a signal to navigate to a new screen. When I come back to this screen, I need this value to be set to null, or else it is going to navigate to the screen again.

Comment: Maybe you want a [SharedFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/)